# Bottleneck in CSV Import with Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate();

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(); to import CSV data from a .csv file to Google Sheets. It takes like 8 seconds to update the import Sheet in my test document, but in production document it takes more than 60 seconds. That's because a lot of formulas are referencing the CSV import Sheet, and Sheets recalculate formulas while the script is running.

I don't know how to manage this bottleneck and don't let sheets recalculate until script is finished. Any ideas?

```
for (const [txtFileSheet, txtFileId] of list) {
    sheetPaste = ss.getSheetByName(`${txtFileSheet}`) || ss.insertSheet(`${txtFileSheet}`, 200); sh.activate();
    sheetId = sheetPaste.getSheetId();
    sheetPaste.clearContents();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    tsvUrl = `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${txtFileId}&x=.tsv`;
    tsvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tsvUrl).getContentText();
    resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {data: tsvContent, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId}, delimiter: '\t'}},]};
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss_id);
}
```

This is the loop that import all the CSV files. I read that the SpreadsheetApp.flush() line could cause the recalculation, but I tried and deleting .flush() cause data not being updated in target sheets.

Comment: move out batchUpdate from the for loop and call it after loop ends.

Comment: As the previous comment, try moving out the `Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss_id);` row from the loop. If not, please share a sample of your sheet and include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @alsanmph Thank you for replying. About `the deletion request works good and script running time is reduced by half, but still very high compared with a second csv file with same data but pasted in a sheet not related with formulas in the document. So, when my main csv has new info, the formula recalculation is still being triggered and running time of script increases.`, I deeply apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @alsanmph From your reply, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I think that I have to study more.